# PHP Code Igniter using query num_row() getting -1

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

Im using below code to get result from database.
Im expecting to get row count > 0 because I have 1 entry in database.
Instead I'm getting the result below.

```
-1Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [lngID] => 1
            [strRefTable] => team
            [intFirstParent] => 
            [intSecondParent] => 
            [bitHasChild] => 
            [strRefValue] => Automation
            [strShortDesc] => Automation
            [strLongDesc] => Automation
            [strCreatedBy] => 181551
            [dteCreatedDate] => 2019-03-27 09:09:08.000
            [strUpdatedBy] => 181551
            [dteUpdatedDate] => 2019-03-27 09:09:08.000
            [bitActive] => 1
        )

)
```

Where -1 represents the echo of `$query->num_rows()` and the array proves that I have record in database.

```
$query = $db->query($sql);
if(!$query) {
throw new Exception('Server error');
}
echo $query->num_rows();exit();
print_r($query->result());die();
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
$result = $query->result();
}
```

Why do I get -1 as row count?

`UPDATE`

> Using MSSQL

Comment: Please mention your CI VERSION

Comment: Is `count($query->result())` working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible explanation for this behavior (if you use PDO PHP Driver for SQL Server to connect to SQL Server), is that `num_rows()` uses [PDOStatement::rowCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-rowcount?view=sql-server-2017) and based on documentation, the result will be `-1` if you execute `SELECT` statement and do not use approipriate cursor type.

> Returns the number of rows added, deleted, or changed. If the last SQL
>   statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT
>   statement, a PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY cursor returns -1. A
>   PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL ABLE cursor returns the number of rows in the
>   result set.

Comment: will this condition `$query->num_rows() !== 0` always get non empty query?

Comment: @guradio Probably yes (with PHP 7.1.2 and PDO PHP Driver for SQL Server 4.0.3 I get this result), but `num_rows()` seems to be driver dependent, so choose another way to count rows - fetch all rows in array and count the elements in array or just implement counter in `while { ... fetch ...}` loop.

Comment: i see then the best way is to just count the `$query->result()` if result is greater than 0?

Comment: @guradio Yes, I think this approach is reasonable. But, this is really driver dependent.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be a [bug in an older version](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/ef795ac23320c4636152af03c8600f2115f1e6e3) of CodeIgniter.

Try upgrading your version of CodeIgniter, or, if not possible, directly query the number of rows using a `COUNT(*)` query or using PHP's `count()` function on the full result set.

Comment: I have a question would checking for not `$query->num_rows() !== 0` also mean that I get result from the query?

Comment: @guradio - `->query()` is the costly part; it talks to the database server.  It should (barring bugs in API) make available the `result`, `num_rows`, errors, etc.